# Time complexity of 2^O(log(n))

Tags: time, big-o

I'm working on a practice exam and came across this problem:

> True or false: 2<sup>O(log(n))</sup> = O(n).

I'm not really sure how to figure this out.

I wanted to try to apply the definition for big-o, but I'm not sure how that works with it because of the power of two.

Comment: Have you tried computing `2**Math.log2(n)` (I'm assuming base 2 log here)?

Comment: The answer was false for anyone wondering.

Comment: What's the rationale behind that result? If it's log base 2, it seems true to me.

Comment: Regardless of what the base actually is, keep in mind that big-O hides an unknown constant of proportionality, which in this case affects the effective value of the base. Conclusion: this expression is not simplifiable.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Prove 2^(O(logn)) = O(n) is not true]
Therefore, (1) cannot be true.

Answer (score -1):

Mathematically this is false, because `e != 2` it should be `e^O(logn) = O(n)`, but i guess it depends on the context because in terms of time complexity of a function or program, this almost true. If the question specifies its base 2 log though, it is totally true.

Comment: The question does not specify, but my professor said to assume base 2 if not explicitly given.

Comment: I would think that it is still true if we assume base e as 2^ln(x) is bounded by a constant multiple of x as shown in this link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%28ln%28x%29%29%2Fx